# C++ - using decltype with enum contained within a templated class

Tags: c++, enums, typedef, decltype

I have a template class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  enum Mode { Mode1, Mode2, Mode3 };
  // ...
};
```

I instantiate this:

```
Foo<float> foo;
// ...
auto m = Foo<float>::Mode1;
```

But it seems to me an unnecessary redundancy to include a source dependency on the type I used when instantiating the Foo template. The classic solution would be a `typedef` on the entire type:

```
typedef Foo<float> FooType;
FooType foo;
// ...
auto m = FooType::Mode1;
```

But it seems to me that the compiler ought to be able to derive the type from the actual instance variable. So something like this instead:

```
Foo<float> foo;
// ...
typedef decltype(foo) FooType;
auto m = FooType::Mode1;
```

This compiles. What puzzles me is why I cannot do the last part as a single expression:

```
auto m = typename decltype(foo)::Mode1;
```

This results in the compiler error "Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction".

The reason why I want to do this at all is because I have substantially more template parameters than just `T` and while the top-level typedef is probably the most sensible solution I'd like to know why my use of decltype on a single line doesn't work.

I'm using Clang 3.0 and I'm not able to use -std=c++11 so I only have use of the default C++ features in Clang 3.0. Unfortunately I can't use enum classes in this version.

Comment: `decltype` *is* a C++11 feature, and so is that use of `auto`.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast yes, I have access to the default C++ features in Clang 3.0, which includes some C++11 features such as `auto` and `decltype`. I just can't turn on `-std=c++11` as this is a custom third-party Clang build that has this option disabled.

Comment: That seems very confusing. It seems to me that it should either be defaulted to C++11 with all the features the compiler has, or defaulted to an older standard with no C++11 features unless you have the option.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using g++ 4.8.2.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  enum Mode { Mode1, Mode2, Mode3 };
};

int main()
{
   Foo<float> foo;
   auto m = decltype(foo)::Mode1;
}
```

The additional `typename` is the problem.

Comment: I actually get the same error message with or without `typename` so I left it in as I wasn't sure if it would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `decltype`, which is a feature that has been [introduced in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), therefore it is not possible to use it in C++03.

Fortunately `decltype` has been [introduced in Clang 2.9](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx11) (just like `auto`) and is available by using `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`.

Your code compiles just fine using C++11:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  enum Mode { Mode1, Mode2, Mode3 };
  // ...
};


int main() {
    Foo<float> foo;
    // ...
    auto m = decltype(foo)::Mode1;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f87cecef8bdd3a6d)

Comment: Is C++03 the default dialect for Clang 3.0?

Comment: So the problem may be partial support for `decltype` then? Given that the keyword is recognised and does work in the two-line version, it's plausible that its use in the one-line version simply isn't supported - perhaps erroneous to assume that `decltype` "returns" a type in this version of the compiler (otherwise `decltype(foo)::Mode1` would work)?